# Alter mysql result for JSON to index by key

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a mysql result that I'm fetching as an array and encoding to JSON like so:

```
$getDisplayPage = "
SELECT p.id as pageID, page_type_id, display_id, slide_order, duration, background_img, pn.ID as panel_id, panel_type_id, cont_id, c.ID as contID, content 
FROM pages p
inner join panels pn
on p.id = pn.page_id 
inner join content c
on pn.cont_id = c.id
WHERE p.active = 1
and pn.active = 1
AND p.display_id = '".$display."'
";

$showDisplayResult = $mysqlConn->query($getDisplayPage);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($showDisplayResult))
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
$showDisplays = json_encode($rows);
```

Which returns a row for each entry, but I need to somehow change it to index by page ID. If you see my JSON below, it returns the correct data but it should actually only have 3 objects/rows as opposed to 5. I need to be able to access all attributes of a given pageID. How can I alter this to give me the correct JSON object?

```
[{"pageID":"93",
    "page_type_id":"2",
    "display_id":"2",
    "slide_order":null,
    "duration":"74",
    "background_img":"images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id":"86",
    "panel_type_id":"2",
    "cont_id":"138",
    "contID":"138",
    "content":"\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nLeft 93<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"},
{"pageID":"93",
    "page_type_id":"2",
    "display_id":"2",
    "slide_order":null,
    "duration":"74",
    "background_img":"images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id":"87",
    "panel_type_id":"3",
    "cont_id":"139",
    "contID":"139",
    "content":"\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nRight 93<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"},
{"pageID":"95",
    "page_type_id":"1",
    "display_id":"2",
    "slide_order":null,
    "duration":"123",
    "background_img":"images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id":"90",
    "panel_type_id":"1",
    "cont_id":"142",
    "contID":"142",
    "content":"\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nTesting a full page for ID 95<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"},
{"pageID":"105",
    "page_type_id":"2",
    "display_id":"2",
    "slide_order":null,
    "duration":"54",
    "background_img":"images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id":"97",
    "panel_type_id":"2",
    "cont_id":"149",
    "contID":"149",
    "content":"\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nThis is left content<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"},
{"pageID":"105",
    "page_type_id":"2",
    "display_id":"2",
    "slide_order":null,
    "duration":"54",
    "background_img":"images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id":"98",
    "panel_type_id":"3",
    "cont_id":"150",
    "contID":"150",
    "content":"\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nThis is right content<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"}]
```

Comment: So, which of the duplicates do you want to keep? They aren't 100% similar. Also, this should be pretty straight forward. Just iterate through the result and create a new array with the format you want.

Comment: ...you can actually already do this in your `while`-loop. Example: `$rows[$row['pageID']] = $row;`. That will give you the `pageID`-value as key. It will only keep the last of each page, though.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: They aren't actually duplicates because the children of each page ID are different panels with different panel types and contents, so I need all of that data just indexed by pageID. I'm trying to use it to dictate, by panel_id, which content to display

Comment: Could I do a foreach as well maybe?

Comment: You need to show us the expected result. I have no idea what you want it to look like. If you want to keep all items, you can't do as I suggested since multiple items in an array can't have the same key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$getDisplayPage = "
SELECT p.id as pageID, page_type_id, display_id, slide_order, duration, background_img, pn.ID as panel_id, panel_type_id, cont_id, c.ID as contID, content 
FROM pages p
inner join panels pn
on p.id = pn.page_id 
inner join content c
on pn.cont_id = c.id
WHERE p.active = 1
and pn.active = 1
AND p.display_id = '".$display."'
";

$showDisplayResult = $mysqlConn->query($getDisplayPage);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($showDisplayResult))
    {
        $rows[$row['pageID']][] = $row;
    }
$showDisplays = json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. This is how I want the JSON to display for sure, now I can work on parsing it properly!